# Grails many-to-many cascade saving in a loop

Tags: hibernate, grails, many-to-many, batch-insert

I have a many-to-many relation between class A and B, A owns the relation. **so A has responsibility to cascade save B and to update join table .**

pseudo code :

```
A {
     hasMany = [bCollection : B]
}

B {
     hasMany = [aCollection : A]
     belongsTo = A
}
```

I have a loop for batch insert

```
        // transaction begin and hibernate session opened
            for(int i in 1..10){
               b = new B(...)                       
               a.addToBCollection(b)
               a.save(flush:true)
               ...
            }
   //transaction committed
```

All ten b instances were saved with cascade saving from A to B, each b instance has a generated id (1001 ~ 1011)

```
 table b

    1001 b1

    1002 b2

    1003 b3

    ...
```

what is strange is that  there is only one record in join table and it's the last b instance which is taken account, which means in join table i have one record :

```
join table a_b

(a.id,1011)
```

have you any idea ?

thank you : )

Comment: when i tried the domain,it works perfectly as you expected for me.

Comment: Do you call the `b.save(flush:true)` after `a.save(flush:true)`? There maybe the problem.

Comment: I tried this code, user = new User();
            for(int i in 1..5){
                Customer customer = new Customer()
                user.addToCustomer(customer)
                user.save(flush:true)
                i++
                render customer
            }
            println user.customer
            render user